# Easy way to see the requests QGIS makes to a remote server?

Tags: qgis, wmts, debugging

I'm attempting to debug an issue with a remote ArcGis Server's WMTS as seen from GeoServer. I can see the requests GeoTools is making (because they throw an error and get logged). However the service works in QGIS (3.0 if that makes a difference) and I would like to know what the difference in the requests is.

I know I can set up wireshark or some such but I hoped there was a way of getting QGIS to log the URLs being requested directly via a flag or setting?.

Comment: Can't see a way, or an option, the other possibility is to set up a logging http proxy and point QGIS to that via the Network config dialog. But wireshark might be easier. Maybe you need a QGIS compiled with the debug option?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### For QGIS 3.14 Pi and up

Just hit F12 and you will get the network logger panel (the QGIS Network Logger plugin is now integrated into QGIS core).

#### For QGIS 3.6 up to 3.14 Pi

For QGIS 3.6 and more recent versions, there is a useful plugin called
[QGIS Network Logger](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgisnetworklogger/), developed by Richard Duivenvoorde.

It is much easier to check the requests sent out by QGIS (sent via the QgsNetworkAccessManager).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It seems there is no easy way to do this **in** QGis, so I solved it by adding a simple proxy, [Python Logging Proxy](https://github.com/willthames/python-logging-proxy) which "does what it says on the can".

I modified the file `LoggingProxyHTTPHandler.py` to comment out line 105

```
print response.content
```

since I didn't need to see the "contents" of the images being sent back. Then to run the proxy all you do is

```
python ./proxy.py
```

And in QGis go to `Settigns`->`Options`->`Network` and turn on the use proxy for web access and fill in `localhost` and `8000` for the Host and Port.

[image]
Then every time QGis requests a WMTS (or other web image) you will see the request and the response in the terminal.

Comment: This will work with requests made with the QgsNetworkAccessManager only I guess, not with plugins using another function such as using urllib or requests.

Comment: I would hope all requests went through the AccessManager, otherwise people with proxies are stuffed.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share two other proxies I used with @Ian's approach on Linux:

1. squid: text logs, should be sufficient for general use

   https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html.en

   default port: 3128
2. fiddler: GUI proxy, supports tile previews

   https://www.telerik.com/blogs/fiddler-for-linux-beta-is-here

   default port: 8888