# WMS raster deforms, wraps while panning or zooming in and out

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, wms, autocad-map

I have set up a WMS raster service in the native EPSG:2462 using GeoServer and I am trying to use it in Autocad Map 2017, the service seems OK at the first insert moment, but then the image wraps while panning or zooming in and out.

The raster EPSG code and project EPSG code are the same, EPSG:2462 so it doesn't have to reproject on the fly.

I noticed that if manually reproject raster and add as a new layer with the native EPSG:32634, and then add it to the project which also has the EPSG:32634 in Autocad Map 2017, the issue disappear. It is a solution, but I don't want to reproject all of my data because of that.

Screenshot of the map:

[image]

The vector lines are the path where the image should be close to, but it doesn't, it just get deformed and wrapped around randomly.

[image]

Comment: please add the actual WMS requests being made by autocad, it looks like it isn't making requests correctly

Comment: http://localhost:9191/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: This is the Autocad Map OGC WKT:      PROJCS["Albanian87.GK-4",GEOGCS["Albanian87.LL",DATUM["Albanian87",SPHEROID["KRASOV",6378245.000,298.30000000],TOWGS84[0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.00000000]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["false_easting",4500000.000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0.000],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1.000000000000],PARAMETER["central_meridian",21.00000000000000],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0.00000000000000],UNIT["Meter",1.00000000000000]]

Comment: that isn't the request it is making for the WMS map - See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282662/is-there-any-easy-way-to-see-the-requests-qgis-makes-to-a-remote-server for a way to track requests made by a client