# ArcGIS WFS-T(Transactional) Service not able to edit in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs, editing, wfs-t

I have published as WFS-T(Transactional) Service for Enterprise data of one Feature class through ArcMap 10.6. Using that WFS URL I have connected in QGIS 3.6 as WFS connection, I can see the data. But I am trying to create one feature or delete feature or update feature not saving the edits. It's giving below error:

> ```
> Commit errors : Could not commit changes to layer layername
> ```

In ArcGIS server log having below error:

> Method failed.HRESULT = 0x80070057 : The parameter is incorrect

Comment: Afaik WFS-data is only for display, not for committing changes. Once you download the data and save it locally, you may edit it.

Comment: can you check the log file to find out exactly what message QGIS sent (you might need this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282662/is-there-any-easy-way-to-see-the-requests-qgis-makes-to-a-remote-server?rq=1 )

Comment: @Erik A WFS is for data download, a WFS-T allows changes to the original data, not a copy on your PC.

Comment: is the layer actually called `layername`