# QGIS 3.10.x WMS Problem

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, wms

Using Ubuntu 18.04.

I have problems loading UK Environment Agency WMS layers. This first arose when I installed QGIS 3.10 and persists in QGIS 3.10.1.

It appears that when QGIS makes a WMS request it adds the current version to the User-Agent string, so in version QGIS 3.10.1 this results in "Mozilla/5.0 QGIS/3.10.1-A Coruña" and that the "ñ" character is causing the request to be rejected.

I wonder if there is any way around this problem? For example, would it be possible bypass the built-in QGIS mechanism for making WMS requests, perhaps using a file? If so, what would such a file look like?

This is an example of an  Environment Agency WMS URL:

https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/lidar-composite-digital-surface-model-dtm-2m/wms

Comment: Maybe it will sound stupid, but have you tried some alternatives of [`'Ñ'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%91) like `'ny'` or `'nh'` etc.?

Comment: You need to report this as a NGINX bug and to the Environment Agency -  as work round you could try a proxy to change the user agent string (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/283493/79 for an example)

Comment: I've done that Ian, they say it's a QGIS problem. Not quite sure why you've closed this, it was what seemed like a reasonable request for help to get round a problem.

Comment: I request that this question be reopened on the grounds that it was not off-topic. I explained the background to my problem and asked two polite and valid questions about a possible solutions. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do they say what the problem is? Have they referenced a standard that shows this character code violates it?

Comment: No, nothing like that. All the EA said was that it was a QGIS problem and that they weren't going to do anything about it. An Anglocentric server I guess that will only accept 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: @nhopton its not what the server can accept, but what the client is sending. The HTTP standards and associated RFCs specify what clients are supposed to do to send non-ASCII content, and it looks like QGIS isn't doing that. Some web servers ignore the standard and go "oh, I assume this is UTF-8" which is nice of them but breaks any standard clients that are validly using other encodings. QGIS should encode its User-Agent string correctly.

Comment: I've now seen your QGIS bug report (which you maybe should have referenced in your question).

Comment: Well, perhaps @spacedman. But my question was about finding a solution to a presented problem, not about QGIS user-agent strings. I only mentioned this as background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102199/discussion-between-spacedman-and-nhopton).

Comment: Other than running QGIS behind a proxy and changing the user-agent string, another workaround would be to cascade the environment agency service through another WMS say MapServer or GeoServer

Comment: creating a local static version of the GetCapabilities response of the EA service allows QGIS to generate correct requests, but the user agent issue still exists so so map is returned

Comment: Meta GIS SE offers advice on whether this question is on-topic at https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4346/when-and-how-should-we-are-not-a-gis-software-support-site-be-invoked  If it has already had a bug report submitted, and the question is about where you are stuck developing a workaround for it, then I think the bug number and a link to it should be included in the question.

Comment: The bug was fixed in master https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/32766 and now is also fixed in 3.10 branch https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/33389