# QGIS Desktop WFS GetCapabilities fails with "Unexpected end of file"

Tags: qgis, getcapabilities

When I am trying to add `WFS` layers with QGIS Desktop it works: `GetCapabilities` request is sent and I can add any layer I want. However when another person using other machine and QGIS Desktop tries to do the same he gets `unexpected end of file`. If he tries to `GetCapabilities` via browser it works fine. From the image he sent me I see that he has selected same `WFS` version as I am.

Update: installed QGIS network logger and this is what I see on other person's QGIS
[image]
Error text says: "server is unsuitable for that kind of operation"

While on my QGIS it says
[image]

Comment: does he have a proxy server? this question may help with debugging https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282662/easy-way-to-see-the-requests-qgis-makes-to-a-remote-server

Comment: No, he does not have proxy server configured. He uses default installation parameters by the way

Comment: Is the service public

Comment: No, but I as I said GetCapabilieties work if used via browser for that person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error disappeared after QGIS Desktop application was configured to use default Windows proxy.

The person works in an institution where they have "group policies" and use other Windows configurations for managing employee workstations.